# SQL Server Tedious Callback

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure-sql-database, tedious

I can't use the callback of tedious on Request (This is a INSERT request) to make another request just after the first one. Any idea ? Here is my code.

```
function intermediaryPositionSQL(decodeMessage, connection) {
  if (typeof (decodeMessage.latitudeInt) != "undefined" && typeof (decodeMessage.longitudeInt) != "undefined")
  {
    var request = new Request(requestPosQuery, function (error)
    {
      if (error) {
        winston.error(error);
      }
    });
    request.addParameter('v_pos_latitude', TYPES.Float, decodeMessage.latitudeInt);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_longitude', TYPES.Float, decodeMessage.longitudeInt);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_altitude', TYPES.Int, (typeof (decodeMessage.altitude) != "undefined") ? decodeMessage.altitude : null);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_speed', TYPES.Int, (typeof (decodeMessage.speed) != "undefined") ? decodeMessage.speed : null);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_move', TYPES.Int, decodeMessage.move);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_type', TYPES.Int, 2);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_device', TYPES.VarChar, decodeMessage.device);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_timestamp', TYPES.Int, decodeMessage.time);

    request.on('doneInProc', function (rowCount, more, rows) {
        return;
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
  }  else {
    return;
  }
}

function actualPositionSQL(decodeMessage, connection) {
  if (typeof (decodeMessage.latitude) != "undefined" && typeof (decodeMessage.longitude) != "undefined")
  {
    var request = new Request(requestPosQuery, function (error)
    {
      if (error) {
        winston.error(error);
      }
    });
    request.addParameter('v_pos_latitude', TYPES.Float, decodeMessage.latitude);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_longitude', TYPES.Float, decodeMessage.longitude);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_altitude', TYPES.Int, (typeof (decodeMessage.altitude) != "undefined") ? decodeMessage.altitude : null);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_speed', TYPES.Int, (typeof (decodeMessage.speed) != "undefined") ? decodeMessage.speed : null);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_move', TYPES.Int, decodeMessage.move);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_type', TYPES.Int, 1);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_device', TYPES.VarChar, decodeMessage.device);
    request.addParameter('v_pos_timestamp', TYPES.Int, decodeMessage.time);

    request.on('doneInProc', function (rowCount, more, rows) {
        intermediaryPositionSQL(decodeMessage, connection);
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
  }  else {
    intermediaryPositionSQL(decodeMessage, connection);
  }
}
```

This code should just INSERT a first time with a SQL request and then do it again with new values

The error is :

```
error:  RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state
```

Here is the configuration of my Azure SQL Server :

```
var config = {
  userName: '***@***',
  password: '*******',
  server: '******.database.windows.net',
  options: {encrypt: true, database: '******'}
};
```

I tried with doneProc, row and even with done without success. doneProc makes the same error as doneInProc and row / done are not called.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the callback in the Request constructor to call your next query:

```
function firstQuery(param, connection) {
    if (typeof (param.foo) != "undefined" && typeof (param.bar) != "undefined") {
       var request = new Request(firstSQL, function (error, rowCount) {
          if (error) {
             winston.error(error);
          }
          else {
             secondQuery(param, connection);
          }
       });
       // add parameters
       connection.execSql(request)
    }
}
```

according to the [documentation](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-request.html#event_doneInProc) this callback is called when the request is complete. The `doneInProc` and `doneProc` events are only relevant when you're using "stored procedures" on your database server. For a simple "insert" or "select" statement the Constructor callback function is what you want to be using.